Creating a bathymetric map in QGIS 3.34 using GRASS v.surf.idw
I am brand new to QGIS and GIS in general. I am attempting to create a bathymetric map using data I collected myself. I am trying to use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGDr3BrmmNw
The steps I have followed are:

import csv data as a delimitted text layer (my csv file has latitude, longitude, and depth columns)
draw polygon boundary around the points on another layer
use GRASS v.surf.idw to create the raster

use the delimitted text vector layer as the input
use defaults for other inputs
select depth as the attribute value to interpret
run



However, when using the v.surf.idw processing tool, the output is not what is expected. The output raster only has a single band (and the minimum and maximum values are the same number which is 1.033). Essentially there is no raster at all showing up but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.
My full project files are located here: https://github.com/stonepreston/rio_vista_qgis
Can someone take a look and see if I am going way wrong somewhere? It seems simple to do, but I cannot for the life of me get it working.

Set your Advanced parameters -> GRASS GIS region cellsize to > 0. As your data are in decimal degrees, use a rough conversion to meters.
Something like 0.000002 (~20cm) should do given your extent and point spacing.


You can then clip to your extent:



thank you so much. Ive been trying for like two days to figure this out.
